# How to alter objects using map?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, object

I have a class which I use to create objects which could look as follows:

```
import copy
import numpy as np

class AnObject(object):

    def __init__(self, someValue, anArray):

        self.someValue = someValue
        self.anArray = anArray

    def changeArray(self):

        newArray = self.anArray.copy()
        ix = np.random.choice(len(self.anArray))
        newArray[ix] = newArray[ix] + 0.5

        self.anArray = newArray 

        return self
```

Each of the objects has certain values assigned to them as well as an array called `anArray`. Furthermore, I have a function `changeArray` which alters the content of this array; for the sake of simplicity I here just add 0.5 to one of the values in this array.

Now I have another class in which I collect all of those objects to perform certain operations on them which could look like this:

```
class AllMyObjects(object):

    def __init__(self, name = None):

        self.name = name
        self.allObjects = []

    def addObject(self, anObject):

        self.allObjects.append(anObject)

    def changeAllMyObjects(self):

        # just to express that it is not just a one-time thing but needs to be done several times

        for i in xrange(1):

            allObjectsCop = copy.deepcopy(self.allObjects)

            # this returns None for each object!
            allObjectsCop = map(lambda x: x.changeArray(), allObjectsCop)

            self.allObjects.extend(allObjectsCop)
```

The individual objects are stored in a list called `allObjects`, one can add objects to it; one can also delete objects which I do not show to keep the example as minimal as possible.

Now I would like to iterate over all objects, change their attribute `anArray` using the function `changeArray` and add all those changed arrays to the list `allObjects`.

This works fine:

```
myObj = AllMyObjects('Test')

myObj.addObject(AnObject(someValue = 1., anArray = np.array([ 1., 2., 3.])))
myObj.addObject(AnObject(someValue = 2., anArray = np.array([ 4., 5., 6.])))
myObj.addObject(AnObject(someValue = 3., anArray = np.array([ 7., 8., 9.])))

myObj.changeAllMyObjects()

for o in xrange(6):
    print myObj.allObjects[o].anArray
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.]
[ 4.  5.  6.]
[ 7.  8.  9.]
[ 1.5  2.   3. ]
[ 4.   5.   6.5]
[ 7.5  8.   9. ]
```

However, without the

```
return self
```

in `changeArray` it does not work, as

```
map(lambda x: x.changeArray(), allObjectsCop)
```

then only returns `None`.

My question is: How could this be done without the `return self` part? If I call `changeArray` on just one object, I don't want this function to return anything but it should just change the array.

Comment: What happens if you change `allObjectsCop = map(...` to just `map(...` with no assignment?

Comment: @Kevin: That seems to work, at least this toy example. But I do not really get why. map return a list but does not alter the original list it is applied to or am I wrong (well, apparently I am wrong)?

Comment: @Cleb `map` applies its first, callable argument to each element it iterates over in the second argument, and returns a list of the return values. That's it. If you want it to alter its second argument in-place, you must write its first argument accordingly.

Comment: In Python 3 `map` does not produce a list, but an iterator, so neither one would work. Best to use `map` for what it's intended for rather than trying to make it do something it's not.

Comment: @kindall this is true, but the Q is for 2.x

Comment: It's still true in Python 2.x that creating a list of `None` and then throwing it away is a pointless waste of time.

Comment: @kindall: So you would use a for-loop rather than map to alter the elements?!

Comment: Yes. Because you aren't mapping anything.

Comment: @kindall: Ok, I just thought that a map might be faster but yes, the for-loop works fine. Thanks for your comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is designed to transform something into something else and then return a new iterable with the altered values. since you want to cause side effects, you could do something like:

```
for x in l:
    x.func()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not really see how I can extend my list "allObjects" using your approach in a straightforwrd manner. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: anyway, since you deepcopy the elements ahead of time, after you alter your list, just do something like: `all_elements.extend(new_elements)`